# unable to access content of array by index when created using array.push

Tags: angular, typescript

Whenever i create array at initialization it works fine. i can access it using Array[index].
but whenever i create an empty array **array = []** , and then push array data using push , i cannot access it using Array[index].

```
testAdd: Address[]= [{add: "D/102", loc: 'thane'},{add: "Room No, 106", loc: 'Mumbai'}];
Add : Address[] = [];
this.Add.push({add:"102,ajaynagar", loc 'andheri'});
console.log(this.testAdd[0])  //results:-  {add: "D/102", loc: 'thane'}
console.log(this.Add[0])    // results:- undefined
```

i want to fill up the array using push command from the data coming from database. it fills up correctly but retrieval shows ***undefined***

Comment: what you got in this.Add?

Comment: Is ``Add : Address[] = [];`` still reference to ``this.Add`` or it's variable defined just there?

Comment: ':' expected. Change `this.Add.push({add:"102,ajaynagar", loc: 'andheri'});`

Answer (score 1):

You missed an **":"** in your push method:

```
this.Add.push({add:"102,ajaynagar", loc: "andheri"});
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct your code, you cant assign value like this, you missed ':'.

```
testAdd: Address[]= [{add: "D/102", loc: 'thane'},{add: "Room No, 106", loc: 'Mumbai'}];
Add : Address[] = [];
this.Add.push({add:"102,ajaynagar", loc: 'andheri'});
console.log(this.testAdd[0])  //results:-  {add: "D/102", loc: 'thane'}
console.log(this.Add[0])
```